# ManyToManyField causing Django Model Save Problems

Tags: django, django-models

I want to save a Django model instance with a ManyToManyField.  When I try to do so with the create() manager, it produces the following error:

```
 Exception Value:'post' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Here is my model:

```
    class Amenity(models.Model):
       post=models.ManyToManyField(Post,blank=True,null=True)
       name=models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=AMENITIES)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return str(self.name)
```

Here is the relevant part of the view:

```
  if request.POST.get('amenities'):
            amens=request.POST['amenities'].split(',')
            p=int(post.id)      
            for a in amens:
                Amenity.objects.create(post=p,name=a)
            return HttpResponse('success')
```

I'm trying to save multiple amenities at one time and I'd doing so outside of a modelform because I have design in mind and I didn't want to have to create a custom field in this case.

post.id is returning the correct value here, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can solve this:

1) By making another database hit: (which is the safest)

```
p = Post.objects.get(pk=post.id)
if p:
    Amenity.objects.create(post=p, name=a)
else:
    ...
```

2) Passing the id to post_id

```
p = int(post.id)
Amenity.objects.create(post_id=p, name=a)
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, got it working on my pc. First of all as it is Many to Many, sounds better to use posts not post as a model field. Well anyway this is how you do it:

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
for a in amens:
    a = Amenity(name=a)
    a.post.add(post) #better if it said a.posts.add(post)
    a.save()
```

Comment: I already know the post instance. The problem is that the keyword argument "post" is invalid, even though it's a M2M field in my Amenity model.  post_id is not a field and therefore also raising a keyword arg error

Comment: Hi that worked. Thanks for the advice on post vs. posts. It's a good point. I do have some questions: 1)Why can't I create the object with the create() manager?  Why can't I add the post keyword arg to Amenity instance constructor in your edited version? I'm assuming this has to do with M2M through table. Lastly, where does the add method come from? Is it just a python built-in?

Comment: I'd like to substitute Amenity.objects.create with get_or_create but I figure I need to do that with the post parameter included.  It didn't work for create(), so I assume it wouldn't work for get_or_create

Comment: Actually post has nothing to do with get_or_create, because theres no record of it on Amenitie´s table, there a 3rd table that contain that relationship. You can do try: a = Amenity.objects.get(name=a) except: AmenityDoesNotExist: a = Amenity(name=a) [<tab] a.posts.add(post) a.save()

Comment: yeah I should have known that, thanks fceruti. Last question, where did the add() method come from?

Comment: because posts is a list-like object. You need to append stuff, not just assign it directly to the variable, and the name "add" is just the name django developers used in this case, if it was a simple list, it would be append (Actually I´m not really sure if append won´t work). PS: your welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it via `Amenity.objects.create(posts=[p],name=a)` since posts expects a list though I haven't tested it myself - all my `ManyToMany` use a `through` since they add additional metadata.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me. Very useful to know that the M2M field requires a list, though. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok, good to know. After creating an `amenity`, `amenity.posts = [p]` works so I was hoping it'd work as a keyword arg in `create` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass `post.id` to `post` field, cause `post` is m2m and django take care of it. Where you set `post` instance ?

Comment: Right, so I tried earlier to pass the post instance, instead of post.id, and that failed also.